# Roslyn Find Same Node in Changed Document

Tags: c#, roslyn

As we all know Roslyn Syntax Trees are Immutable, so after making changes you need to get a new node.

I'm trying to update a document using the document editor, but I keep getting an error that the node is not found in the syntax tree.

```
public static T FindEquivalentNode<T>(this Document newDocument, T node)
    where T : CSharpSyntaxNode
{
    var root = newDocument.GetSyntaxRootAsync().Result;
    return root.DescendantNodes().OfType<T>()
            .FirstOrDefault(newNode => SyntaxFactory.AreEquivalent(newNode, node));
}
```

When I try to Call this again the document editor:

```
var newFieldDeclaration = documentEditor.GetChangedDocument().FindEquivalentNode(syntaxNode);
documentEditor.ReplaceNode(newFieldDeclaration, propertyDeclaration);
```

I get an error:

> The node is not part of the tree

The newField Declaration is not null it find an equivalent field yet I still get this error, How Can I Replace this node?

Comment: Are you modifying the tree and then try to find something that you located (found) in the original tree? If so, then you can add `new SyntaxAnnotation()`s to a node and then find the same instance of the annotation in the modified tree. See an example here: https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-csharp/blob/63c661bde321a96ffcf9daca1aabac79e0f37929/sonaranalyzer-dotnet/src/SonarAnalyzer.CSharp/Rules/GenericReadonlyFieldPropertyAssignmentCodeFixProvider.cs#L130

Comment: @Tamas Where to they grab out the matching node out of the document, I see them grab a list of annotations but how to find an specific node?

Comment: How did you get the syntax node that you want to find? Isn't it part of the tree that you want to modify? If yes, then the above works. If not, then you can use the [`SyntaxFactory.AreEquivalent`](http://source.roslyn.codeplex.com/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp/Syntax/SyntaxFactory.cs,84069a73c6b638c2). But I would say the latter solution is rarely needed, as you should have a document with a sytax tree that you'd want to modify.

Comment: I just added it to the tree, when I try to grab it back out of the DocumentEditor.GetChangedDocument(), even when I grab out the equivalent node it says it doesn't exist in the tree very weird

Comment: Annotate the node before adding, and then look for the annotation in the resulting tree to locate the node. When you add the node to the tree, the tree is changed, and also the node changes too.

Comment: @Tamas I don't think that is the real issue here, I'm definetly getting out the node can you take a look at the updated question

Comment: I'm not familiar with the `DocumentEditor`, but it looks like it is searching in the original tree: http://source.roslyn.codeplex.com/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Workspaces/Editing/SyntaxEditor.cs,9d1a72ecdbf61c96,references

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You get the node because in your `FindEquivalentNode` method, you are doing that:

```
SyntaxFactory.AreEquivalent(newNode, node)
```

`SyntaxFactory.AreEquivalent` is not return true for "real" same nodes, but for nodes\tokens that are seems equal in their structure (with consideration of `topLevel` parameter).

Back to your question, if you want to call `ReplaceNode` you must have the "real" old node, so you wouldn't get an

> The node is not part of the tree

To achive that, you have a few options, one of them is what @Tamas wrote in comments, use `SyntaxAnnotations`.

Example:

```
//Add annotation to node 
var annotation = new SyntaxAnnotation("your_annotation", "some_data");
node = node .WithAdditionalAnnotations(annotation);

// Now you can change the tree as much you want

// And when you want to get the node from the changed tree 
var annotatedNode = someNode.DescendantNodesAndSelf().
        FirstOrDefault(n => n.GetAnnotations("your_annotation").Any())
```