# How to get semantic model for renamed class without "not found to remove" exception

Tags: c#, roslyn

Here is a script that

1. Identifies the type information for a class using its semantic model
2. Renames the class by replacing its Identifier token
3. Identifies the type information for the renamed class using its semantic model
4. Runs a SyntaxRewriter on the renamed class - the rewriter replaces all ocurrences of the old type info with the new type info.

(I hope) as minimally as possible:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // This class needs to be renamed. We want to use Roslyn and symbols,
    // because string-based replacement would change things that it's not supposed to.
    var someScript = "public class FooBar { public NotFooBar a; FooBar string b; public OtherNamespace.FooBar c; }";

    // Minimal Roslyn boilerplate
    var compilation = CSharpCompilation.Create("CodeGeneration")
        .WithOptions(new CSharpCompilationOptions(OutputKind.DynamicallyLinkedLibrary))
        .AddSyntaxTrees(CSharpSyntaxTree.ParseText(someScript));

    var tree = compilation.SyntaxTrees[0];
    var classDeclaration = tree.GetRoot().DescendantNodes().OfType<ClassDeclarationSyntax>().Single();
    var originalType = compilation.GetSemanticModel(classDeclaration.SyntaxTree).GetDeclaredSymbol(classDeclaration);
    var renamedClass = classDeclaration.ReplaceToken(
        classDeclaration.Identifier,
        SyntaxFactory.Identifier(classDeclaration.Identifier.Text.Replace("Bar", "Baz"))
    );
    var semanticModel = compilation.GetSemanticModel(renamedClass.SyntaxTree);
    var renamedType = semanticModel.GetDeclaredSymbol(renamedClass);
    var rewritten = new TestRewriter(semanticModel, originalType, renamedType).Visit(renamedClass);
    Console.Write(rewritten.GetText());
}

class TestRewriter : CSharpSyntaxRewriter
{
    private readonly SemanticModel _model;
    private readonly ITypeSymbol _replace;
    private readonly ITypeSymbol _replacement;

    public TestRewriter(SemanticModel model, ITypeSymbol replace, ITypeSymbol replacement)
    {
        _model = model;
        _replace = replace;
        _replacement = replacement;
    }

    public override SyntaxNode VisitIdentifierName(IdentifierNameSyntax node)
    {
        return base.VisitIdentifierName(
            _model.GetTypeInfo(node).Type.Equals(_replace)
                ? node.ReplaceToken(node.Identifier, SyntaxFactory.Identifier(_replacement.ToDisplayString()))
                : node
        );
    }
}
```

When running this program, `compilation.GetSemanticModel(renamedClass.SyntaxTree)` causes the following exception

> `System.ArgumentException`: `SyntaxTree` `public class FooBaz{ public NotFooBar a; FooBar string b; public OtherNamespace.FooBar c; }` not found to remove

If, instead of getting a semantic model from the renamed class' tree, the semantic model from the original class' tree is used, then `GetTypeInfo(node)` will (as expected) throw an exception because `node` is not a part of the model's tree.

What step am I missing that would prevent the "not found to remove" exception?

Comment: There is a Renamer API that can do this all for you.

Comment: Thanks, Matt. It looks like Renamer is a part of the Workspaces package, and requires a Solution root. I'll look into it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error that you receive is a result of you searching an element in a SyntaxTree which does not contain said element.

When you call classDeclaration.ReplaceToken you do not actually replace the token in the existing SyntaxTree but rather you generate a new structure which is unrelated to the existing one. When you try to get the semantic model from the renamedClass you use a SyntaxTree not within the Compilation which causes the code to throw an exception.

In order to fix this problem you can replace the node in the existing CompilationUnit and then replace the SyntaxTree in the Compilation. However, you will not be able to find the ClassDeclaration again, as it becomes a new object which does not correspond to the existing "renamedClass" Object.

In order to track the element you can use [SyntaxAnnotations](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44240887) which allow you to add information to a node which can be retrieved later. This could look something along these lines:

```cs
    static void ReplaceClassName()
    {
        // This class needs to be renamed. We want to use Roslyn and symbols,
        // because string-based replacement would change things that it's not supposed to.
        var someScript = "public class FooBar { public NotFooBar a; FooBar b; public OtherNamespace.FooBar c; }";

        // Minimal Roslyn boilerplate
        var compilation = CSharpCompilation.Create("CodeGeneration")
            .WithOptions(new CSharpCompilationOptions(OutputKind.DynamicallyLinkedLibrary))
            .AddSyntaxTrees(CSharpSyntaxTree.ParseText(someScript));
        var oldSyntaxTree = compilation.SyntaxTrees[0];
        var root = oldSyntaxTree.GetRoot();
        var classDeclaration = root.DescendantNodes().OfType<ClassDeclarationSyntax>().Single();
        var originalType = compilation.GetSemanticModel(classDeclaration.SyntaxTree).GetDeclaredSymbol(classDeclaration);
        var renamedClass = classDeclaration.ReplaceToken(
            classDeclaration.Identifier,
            SyntaxFactory.Identifier(classDeclaration.Identifier.Text.Replace("Bar", "Baz"))
        ).WithAdditionalAnnotations(new SyntaxAnnotation("ReplacedClass"));
        root = root.ReplaceNode(classDeclaration, renamedClass);
        compilation = compilation.ReplaceSyntaxTree(oldSyntaxTree, renamedClass.SyntaxTree);
        renamedClass = compilation.SyntaxTrees[0].GetRoot().DescendantNodes().OfType<ClassDeclarationSyntax>().FirstOrDefault(curr => curr.GetAnnotations("ReplacedClass").Any());
        var semanticModel = compilation.GetSemanticModel(compilation.SyntaxTrees[0]);
        var renamedType = semanticModel.GetDeclaredSymbol(renamedClass);
        var rewritten = new TestRewriter(semanticModel, originalType, renamedType).Visit(renamedClass);
        Console.Write(rewritten.GetText());
    }
```

Sadly this will not actually resolve your problem. While you now have a new SemanticModel available, you will not be able to compare the TypeInfo of two different Models as you do in your SyntaxRewriter.

In order to retain your Type information I would advise you to use the SyntaxRewriter to change both the IdentifierName as well as the ClassDeclarationSyntax, as the SyntaxRewriter will visit the nodes first and replace them only afterwards. This could be implemented as follows:

```cs
static void ReplaceClassName()
{
    // This class needs to be renamed. We want to use Roslyn and symbols,
    // because string-based replacement would change things that it's not supposed to.
    var someScript = "public class FooBar { public NotFooBar a; FooBar b; public OtherNamespace.FooBar c; }";

    // Minimal Roslyn boilerplate
    var compilation = CSharpCompilation.Create("CodeGeneration")
        .WithOptions(new CSharpCompilationOptions(OutputKind.DynamicallyLinkedLibrary))
        .AddSyntaxTrees(CSharpSyntaxTree.ParseText(someScript));
    var oldSyntaxTree = compilation.SyntaxTrees[0];
    var root = oldSyntaxTree.GetRoot();
    var classDeclaration = root.DescendantNodes().OfType<ClassDeclarationSyntax>().FirstOrDefault();
    var semanticModel = compilation.GetSemanticModel(classDeclaration.SyntaxTree);
    var originalType = semanticModel.GetDeclaredSymbol(classDeclaration);
    var rewritten = new TestRewriter(semanticModel, originalType).Visit(root);
    Console.Write(rewritten.GetText());
}

class TestRewriter : CSharpSyntaxRewriter
{
    private readonly SemanticModel _model;
    private readonly ITypeSymbol _replace;
    public TestRewriter(SemanticModel model, ITypeSymbol replace)
    {
        _model = model;
        _replace = replace;
    }

    public override SyntaxNode VisitIdentifierName(IdentifierNameSyntax node)
    {
        node = base.VisitIdentifierName(node) as IdentifierNameSyntax;
        if (_model.GetTypeInfo(node).Type.Equals(_replace))
        {
            var oldNode = node;
            node = node.ReplaceToken(

                        node.Identifier,
                        SyntaxFactory.Identifier(node.Identifier.Text.Replace("Bar", "Baz"))
                ).WithLeadingTrivia(oldNode.GetLeadingTrivia()).WithTrailingTrivia(oldNode.GetTrailingTrivia());
        }
        return node;
    }

    public override SyntaxNode VisitClassDeclaration(ClassDeclarationSyntax node)
    {
        var oldNode = node;
        node = base.VisitClassDeclaration(node) as ClassDeclarationSyntax;
        if (_model.GetDeclaredSymbol(oldNode).Equals(_replace))
        {
            return node.WithIdentifier(SyntaxFactory.Identifier(node.Identifier.Text.Replace("Bar", "Baz")));
        }
        return node;
    }
}
```

If you actually have a solution available you could possibly use the [Renamer](http://source.roslyn.io/Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Workspaces/Rename/Renamer.cs.html) class which should do all the work for you.

Comment: Thank you for such a detailed answer! I originally tried to rewrite the declaration and usages in the same rewriter, and ran into a "node doesn't exist in this tree" error. Are you certain that Rewriter overrides never receive a modified Node? For example, if `Visit` returns a changed node, wouldn't `VisitClassDeclaration` receive the changed node?

Comment: Actually that depends on your implementation. If you take a look at the method "VisitClassDeclaration" you will see that I called base.VisitClassDeclaration(node). The base call actually invokes the VisitIdentifierName member. If I had first modified the node and then passed the modified value to the member call of the base class, I would have received a modified node in VisitIdentifierName. However, if you only modify your node after you call the base implementation you should always receive a node from the original tree in your custom Visit-methods.